# In iOS7, status bar default background is not rotating

Tags: ios6, ios7, statusbar, uiinterfaceorientation, uiwindow

I am developing an iPad application for iOS 6 and above. As we know for there is status bar view change. I have added below code to display normal status bar like iOS 6:

In **AppDelegate.mm --> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {

    [application setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    self.window.clipsToBounds =YES;

    self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0,20,self.window.frame.size.width,self.window.frame.size.height-20);
}
```

When I run my application over iOS 6, status bar looks fine for both the orientations. But when I run over iOS 7 simulator and device. **Status bar does move with the rotation, but the black background of status bar is not moving at all.**

Initial - Portrait:
[image]

Rotate - Landscape:
[image]

The same kind of issue comes for all three rotations, rather than Portrait.

Please guide me what could be the solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding subview on UIWindow, set your viewcontroller as root view controller.

***AppDelegate.mm***

```
window.rootViewController = myViewController;
// [window addSubview: myViewController.view];
```

Hope this will help to others.